# Python - import function from same path

Tags: python, function, module

I have two `python scripts` on the same `dir`:

```
db/
  __init__.py
  database.py
  recommendations.py
```

there's is a `function` (not part of any `class`)

```
def collabPlaylist(path)
```

declared inside `database.py`, which I'm trying to bring into `recommendations.py` with

```
from database import collabPlaylist
```

and calling it with:

```
playlist = collabPlaylist('generated_playlists/p1/')
```

but I'm getting:

`ImportError: cannot import name collabPlaylist`.

what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you also trying to import `recommendations` inside `database.py`?

Comment: yesI am. wrong?

Comment: There are workarounds, try searching SO for "circular import".

Comment: @data_garden yes, that is a circular import ergo your error above. IF you absolutely have to import collabPlaylist into recommendations.py (instead of just moving the function there), I would do the import inside the function where you are using planning ot use it ( look up 'local import').

Comment: thanks, removing `circular import` solved it. will look further into it. you can answer and I'll accept it if you wish

Comment: @data_garden It makes more sense if you write your own solution as an answer and [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it) instead.